# Checking the input page size and then manipulating the pageable instance in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

My controller method is something like this:

```
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<PagedResources<T>> getProductsByName(@PathVariable("name") String program,
                @PageableDefault(size = 50) Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<T> assembler)
```

So if we don't pass the `size` param in the URL, by default `page size` will be 50.

This is what I want:

I have 2 constants:

```
defaultPageSize = 50
pageMaxLimit = 100
```

Now,

1. If `size` param is not in URL, pageable should be of `defaultPageSize`
2. If `size` param is present in URL, and it is greater than `pageMaxLimit`, set it to `defaultPageSize`
3. If `size` param is present in URL, and it is lesser than `pageMaxLimit`, use the input `size` param.

I have written a function for this.

```
public int evaluateCurrentPageSize(Pageable pageable, int defaultSize, int maxSize) {
        if (pageable.getPageSize() > maxSize) {
            return defaultSize;
        }
        return pageable.getPageSize();
    }
```

I am stuck at setting a `page size` to the pageable instance, because we don't have anything like `setPageSize()` similar to `getPageSize()`.

How do I achieve this?

EDIT:
I would also like to know how to set these constants from `application.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ensure the page doesn't exceed your maximum**

```
int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
if (pageSize > 50) {
    pageSize = 50;
}

Pageable pr = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageSize);
```

**To configure with application.properties:**

In application.properties, create a property:

```
pageable.default=50
```

Create a configuration class:

```
    @Configuration
    public class PageConfig {

        @Value("${pageable.default}")
        private int pageDefault;

        public int getPageDefault() {
            return pageDefault;
        }

    }
```

In your controller, load that config:

```
 @Autowired
 PageConfig pageConfig;
```

Access the value

```
  pageConfig.getPageDefault(); // 50
```

**All put together, with both questions (using properties, downsizing if over max)**

```
    int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
    if (pageSize > pageConfig.getPageDefault()) {
        pageSize = pageConfig.getPageDefault();
    }

    Pageable pr = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageSize);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did not know about `Pageable pr = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageSize);` Also, `PageConfig` is very helpful. You're awesome :)